# Module 'FirebaseCore' not found

Tags: xcode, firebase, cordova, ionic-framework, cocoapods

Getting this error when I'm trying to build my Ionic app in Xcode.

Any idea of what I'm doing wrong? the Pod file appears to be in the right place.

Have tried changing @import FirebaseCore;" to "#import "FirebaseCore/FirebaseCore.h" and adding pod 'FirebaseCore', :modular_headers => true but Xcode still isn't finding it.

Here's an image of the error:

[error_img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q73P5.png)

Was expecting Xcode to build the same as before (from my_app.xcodeproj file compiled with ionic cordova build ios --prod --release) - as that has worked before this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue you probably have is that when you run ionic cordova or capacitor it builds a project under platforms. When you open xcode, do NOT select the xcode.proj, instead when you open xcode, open from files and select the entire ios folder under platforms.

For example

/Users/$User/Documents/GitHub/$Project/platforms/ios

This because this folder contains the the things like pods and such for firebase and thus throws an error when it cant find them

Comment: great! So did you have a pods file in there?

Comment: Yea all of the pod files were the, opened IOS directory of project (in xcode) instead of the .xcodeproj file that i had opened before. Compiled first time!

Comment: Opening the ios directory didn't work for me, but this answer gave me the AHA! moment I needed: open the .xcworkspace file instead of the .xcodeproj file.